# Irish Weather Warnings App in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

I have been working on this project for a little bit and it's my first major python program. It downloads information about current and upcoming weather warnings for Ireland and displays them with tkinter. Would be grateful of suggestions or critique!

https://github.com/Sn4u/met-eireann-status/tree/master

**met_eireann_status.py**

```
import requests
import json
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from datetime import datetime
import textwrap
from os import getcwd
from randomise_demo import randomise_demo_dates

# read json files with weather information
with open(getcwd() + '\\' + "region_codes.json", "r") as file:
    REGION_CODES = json.loads(file.read())

with open(getcwd() + '\\' + "marine_codes.json", "r") as file:
    MARINE_CODES = json.loads(file.read())

dimensions = {"width": "60", "height": "10", }
style_no_warning = {"foreground": "black", "background": "green", "font": "Helvetica 11 bold"}
style_bold = {"font": "Helvetica 9 bold"}
level_to_style = {
    "Yellow": {"foreground": "Black", "background": "yellow"},
    "Orange": {"foreground": "Black", "background": "orange"},
    "Red": {"foreground": "Black", "background": "red"},
}

obj_dict = {}  # Card:WarningInfo


class WarningInfo:
    """Stores necessary weather warning information"""

    def __init__(self, json_data):

        print(json_data)
        self.cap_id = json_data['capId']
        self.id = json_data['id']
        self.type = json_data['type']
        self.severity = json_data['severity']
        self.certainty = json_data['certainty']
        self.level = json_data['level']
        self.issued = json_data['issued']
        self.updated = json_data['updated']
        self.onset = json_data['onset']
        self.expiry = json_data['expiry']
        self.headline = json_data['headline']
        self.description = json_data['description']
        self.regions = json_data['regions']
        self.status = json_data['status']

        self.delta = None
        self.delta_msg = None
        self.style = level_to_style[self.level]

        if update_time(self) == 'expired':
            print("warning is expired")
        else:
            Card().make(self)


class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(root, **dimensions, bg="#CDCDCD")
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.primary = None
        self.headline_label = None
        self.primary_info_frame = None
        self.certainty_frame = None
        self.delta_frame = None
        self.severity_frame = None
        self.certainty_label = None
        self.certainty_text = None
        self.delta_label = None
        self.delta_text = None
        self.severity_label = None
        self.severity_text = None
        self.secondary = None
        self.dates_frame = None
        self.issued_text = None
        self.issued_time = None
        self.expiry_text = None
        self.expiry_time = None
        self.desclabel = None

    def make(self, data: WarningInfo):
        obj_dict[self] = data

        self.primary = tkinter.Frame(self.frame, background=data.level, **dimensions)
        self.primary.pack(fill='both', side='left')
        self.primary.bind('<Button-1>', self.display_extra)

        self.headline_label = tkinter.Label(self.primary, data.style, text=data.headline, justify='center',
                                            wraplength=500, font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), width=59)
        self.headline_label.pack(side='top')

        self.primary_info_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.primary, background=data.level)
        self.certainty_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.primary_info_frame)
        self.delta_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.primary_info_frame)
        self.severity_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.primary_info_frame)
        self.primary_info_frame.pack(side='left')
        self.certainty_frame.pack(side='left')
        self.delta_frame.pack(side='left')
        self.severity_frame.pack(side='left')

        self.certainty_label = tkinter.Label(self.certainty_frame, data.style, text="Certainty: ")
        self.certainty_text = tkinter.Label(self.certainty_frame, data.style, font=('Helvetica', 9, 'bold'),
                                            text=data.certainty)
        self.certainty_label.pack(side='left')
        self.certainty_text.pack(side='left')

        self.delta_label = tkinter.Label(self.delta_frame, data.style, text=data.delta_msg)
        self.delta_text = tkinter.Label(self.delta_frame, data.style, text=data.delta,
                                        font=('Helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
        self.delta_label.pack(side='left')
        self.delta_text.pack(side='left')
        self.severity_label = tkinter.Label(self.severity_frame, text="Severity: ")
        self.severity_text = tkinter.Label(self.severity_frame, data.style, font=('Helvetica', 9, 'bold'),
                                           text=data.severity)

        self.headline_label.bind('<Button-1>', self.display_extra)

        # secondary
        self.secondary = tkinter.Frame(self.frame, **dimensions, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN, borderwidth=4)

        self.dates_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.secondary)
        self.issued_text = tkinter.Label(self.dates_frame, text='Issued: ')
        self.issued_time = tkinter.Label(self.dates_frame, text=friendly_time(data.issued),
                                         font=('Helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
        self.expiry_text = tkinter.Label(self.dates_frame, text='Expiry: ')
        self.expiry_time = tkinter.Label(self.dates_frame, text=friendly_time(data.expiry),
                                         font=('Helvetica', 9, 'bold'))

        self.dates_frame.pack(side='top')
        self.issued_text.pack(side='left')
        self.issued_time.pack(side='left')
        self.expiry_text.pack(side='left')
        self.expiry_time.pack(side='left')

        self.desclabel = tkinter.Label(self.secondary, text=self.format_description(data),

                                       height=4)
        self.desclabel.pack(side='bottom')
        self.secondary.visible = False

    def delete(self):
        self.frame.destroy()

    def display_extra(self, _):
        """toggle secondary panel visibility"""

        def forget_old():
            self.certainty_frame.pack_forget()
            self.delta_frame.pack_forget()

        if self.secondary.visible is False:
            self.secondary.pack(fill='both', side='right', expand=True)

            forget_old()
            self.certainty_frame.pack(side='top', anchor='w')
            self.delta_frame.pack(side='top', anchor='w')
        else:
            self.secondary.pack_forget()

            forget_old()
            self.certainty_frame.pack(side='left')
            self.delta_frame.pack(side='left')

        self.secondary.visible = not self.secondary.visible

    def format_description(self, warn: WarningInfo):
        return textwrap.TextWrapper(max_lines=3).fill(text=warn.description)

    def create_non_warning(self, message, style=None):
        obj_dict[self] = None
        if style is None:
            style = style_no_warning
        self.frame.configure(height=10, width=60)
        self.headline_label = tkinter.Label(self.frame, style, text=message)
        self.headline_label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)


def rdel():
    """recursively delete all Warning_info and Card objects"""
    for card in obj_dict:
        card.frame.destroy()
    obj_dict.clear()


def download_json(selected_region):
    if selected_region == "Demo":
        with open(getcwd() + '\\' + "demo_weather_warning.json", "r") as f:
            response = json.loads(f.read())
    else:
        if selected_region in REGION_CODES:
            areacode = REGION_CODES[selected_region]
        else:
            areacode = MARINE_CODES[selected_region]
            Card().create_non_warning(message="Feature Unsupported!")
            return
        met_url = f"https://www.met.ie/Open_Data/json/warning_{areacode}.json"
        try:
            response = requests.get(met_url).json()  # downloads latest json from api with given region
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title='Warning_info',
                                         message='Could not reach Met Eireann API. Please try again later')
            return
    return response


def friendly_time(date_input):
    """format time to be displayed on warning card
    Example: 2021-02-21T14:45:06-00:00 -> Feb 21 At 14:45"""
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
    return date_object.strftime('%b %d At %H:%M')


def update_time(obj: WarningInfo):
    """For every warning object, compare current time to expiration time to check if warning is expired.
    If expired, return 'expired'. Otherwise check if warning is in place or not in place yet
    and assign time delta and correct label to the object attribute"""
    t_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
    current_time = datetime.now()

    # remove utc offset from times
    onset_time = datetime.strptime(obj.onset[:-6], t_format)
    expiry_time = datetime.strptime(obj.expiry[:-6], t_format)

    if current_time > onset_time and current_time > expiry_time:
        # we are past both the onset and the expiration
        # destroy tkinter warning widgets and remove Warnings object.

        return "expired"

    elif current_time > onset_time:
        # warning is in place but not expired
        # display time until expiration
        obj.delta = ':'.join(str(expiry_time - current_time).split(':')[:2])
        obj.delta_msg = 'Time until expiration: '

    else:
        # warning is not in place yet
        # display time until warning onset
        obj.delta = ':'.join(str(onset_time - current_time).split(':')[:2])
        obj.delta_msg = 'Time until onset: '


def flash_red():
    """Make the headline of warning card flash red and white"""
    for card, info in obj_dict.items():
        try:
            if info.level == "Red":
                if card.headline_label["background"] != '#be0000':
                    card.headline_label.configure(backgroun='#be0000')
                else:
                    card.headline_label.configure(background='red')
        except AttributeError:
            pass


def refresh(_=None):
    """Called when refresh button is pressed. Deletes all card objects and displays new ones"""
    rdel()
    randomise_demo_dates()
    selected_region = combox.get()  # gets the selected region from combo box
    response = download_json(selected_region)
    if response is None:
        return None

    # if there are no warnings, display it as a message
    if len(response) == 0:
        Card().create_non_warning(message="There are no warnings for the selected region")
    else:
        create_object(response, selected_region)


def create_object(response, selected_region):
    """creates a WarningInfo class object for all warnings that match chosen location"""

    for dict_entry in response:
        if selected_region == 'Demo' or selected_region == "All counties":
            WarningInfo(dict_entry)
        elif REGION_CODES[selected_region] in dict_entry['regions']:
            print(REGION_CODES[selected_region])
            WarningInfo(dict_entry)


def update_combox_val():
    """Changes between marine zones and counties to be displayed on the combo box widget"""
    sea_val = sea_box_val.get()
    if sea_val == 1:
        combox.configure(values=[i for i in MARINE_CODES.keys()])
        location_label.configure(text="Select Marine Zone: ")
    else:
        combox.configure(values=[i for i in REGION_CODES.keys()])
        location_label.configure(text="Select County: ")


def info_action():
    info_window = tkinter.Toplevel()
    info_window.title('Information')
    info_window.iconbitmap("Assets/MetEireann logo-02.ico")
    info_text = tkinter.Label(info_window, justify='left', wraplength=666)
    with open(getcwd() + '\\' + "info.txt", "r") as text:
        info_text['text'] = text.read()
    info_text.pack()
    info_btn['state'] = 'disabled'
    info_btn['relief'] = 'sunken'

    def info_close():
        info_btn['state'] = 'normal'
        info_btn['relief'] = 'raised'
        info_window.destroy()

    info_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", info_close)


# GUI
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Met Eireann Status")
root.iconbitmap("Assets/MetEireann logo-02.ico")

options_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(root, relief=tkinter.RAISED, borderwidth=5)
options_frame.pack(fill='x')

location_label = tkinter.Label(options_frame, text="Select County:", width=14)
location_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=4)

combox = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(options_frame, values=[i for i in REGION_CODES.keys()], state="readonly")
combox.current(27)  # sets default for the combo box
combox.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=4)

refresh_button = tkinter.Button(options_frame, text='Refresh', command=refresh)
refresh_button.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=4, pady=5)
root.bind('<Return>', refresh)

sea_box_val = tkinter.IntVar()
sea_check_box = tkinter.Checkbutton(options_frame, variable=sea_box_val, text="Search Marine Warnings",
                                    command=update_combox_val)
sea_check_box.grid(column=4, row=0)

info_btn = tkinter.Button(options_frame, bitmap="info", width=25, command=info_action)
info_btn.grid(column=6, row=0, padx=4)


def tick():
    root.after(1000, tick)
    flash_red()


tick()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Codereview, and great first question!

Comment: I'm worried that I didn't ask a specific enough question and included too much code. Let me know if this is the case and I will include more background information and my concerns regarding the project